# javascript problem replacing string occurrence

Tags: javascript

i have the following code in my html page and as you can see i am trying to replace the occurrence  of `"state"` with `"item"` and `"number"` with `"count"` in the string `s`

here is an example of the response text :     `[{"number":177,"state":"ABONDONNE"},{"number":132,"state":"ENCOURS"},{"number":6,"state":"GAGNE"},{"number":195,"state":"PERDU"},{"number":2,"state":"REPORTE"}]`

here is my javascript code:

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            xhttp.onload = function() {
                var s = xhttp.responseText;
                s.replaceAll("state","item");
                s.replaceAll("number","count");

                var jsonArray = JSON.parse(s);
                console.log(s);
            }
            
            xhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/plot");
            xhttp.send();
```

my problem is that after this code i get the same response text in the console:

```
[{"number":177,"state":"ABONDONNE"},{"number":132,"state":"ENCOURS"},{"number":6,"state":"GAGNE"},{"number":195,"state":"PERDU"},{"number":2,"state":"REPORTE"}]
```

**what i am missing?**

Comment: replaceAll returns a new string ... with replaced text ... So you need to assign it to the original variable like below:
```
s = s.replaceAll ("", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a new string returned by `replaceAll` function.

```
let updatedString = s.replaceAll("state","item")
```

Comment: thank you , but  i think i should delete the question

Answer (score 1):

You don't assign functions's result anywhere. Change to:

```
s = s.replaceAll("state","item");
s = s.replaceAll("number","count");
```